# Spring Data JPA fetches all columns when mapped model is included

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> **Interface based projection** - I want to select only few columns from **Product** and **ProductImages** DB tables.
>
> **Issue:** If I mention mapped model in interface `public Set<ProductImagesDBResult> getProductImages();` it fetches all columns. 
>   from both Product and ProductImages tables.
>
> **Note:** If I comment this out, it fetches only selected fields.

**Entity models Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Product {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
   private Set<ProductImage> productImages;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
   private Category category;

   private String sku;  
   private String slug; 
   private String title;    
   private String description;  
   private BigDecimal oldPrice; 
   private BigDecimal newPrice; 
   private int status;

   /* getters and setters */
}
```

**Entity model ProductImage.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_images")
public class ProductImage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Product product; 

    private String image;   
    private int isDefault;  
    private int imgOrder;
}
```

**ProductDetailsDBResult.java** (Projection interface)

```
public interface ProductDetailsDBResult {

    public long getId();
    public String getSlug();
    public String getTitle();
    public Set<ProductImagesDBResult> getProductImages();

   interface ProductImagesDBResult {
       public long getId();
       public String getImage();
   }

   /* getters and setters */
}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    Optional<ProductDetailsDBResult> findBySlug(String slug);
}
```

**ProductService.java**

```
ProductDetailsDBResult p = productRepository.findBySlug(slug)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RecordNotFoundException("Invalid product slug " + slug));
```

The issue is:

When this line is commented out:

```
public interface ProductDetailsDBResult {
    /* other get methods ... */
    // public Set<ProductImagesDBResult> getProductImages();
}
```

**Logs show (correct SQL as only mentioned columns are fetched):**

```
Hibernate: select product0_.id as col_0_0_, product0_.slug as col_1_0_, product0_.title as col_2_0_ from products product0_ where product0_.slug=?
```

But when this line is uncommented: `public Set<ProductImagesDBResult> getProductImages();`

**SQL fetches all fields from both Product, Category and ProductImages tables:** (Product is mapped with Category and ProductImages models)

```
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_5_, product0_.category_id as categor11_5_, product0_.created_at as created_2_5_, product0_.description as descript3_5_, product0_.new_price as new_pric4_5_, product0_.old_price as old_pric5_5_, product0_.sku as sku6_5_, product0_.slug as slug7_5_, product0_.status as status8_5_, product0_.title as title9_5_, product0_.updated_at as updated10_5_ from products product0_ where product0_.slug=?

Hibernate: select category0_.id as id1_0_0_, category0_.description as descript2_0_0_, category0_.is_featured as is_featu3_0_0_, category0_.preview_image as preview_4_0_0_, category0_.slug as slug5_0_0_, category0_.title as title6_0_0_ from categories category0_ where category0_.id=?

Hibernate: select productima0_.product_id as product_5_4_0_, productima0_.id as id1_4_0_, productima0_.id as id1_4_1_, productima0_.image as image2_4_1_, productima0_.img_order as img_orde3_4_1_, productima0_.is_default as is_defau4_4_1_, productima0_.product_id as product_5_4_1_ from product_images productima0_ where productima0_.product_id=?
```

How can I fetch only the mentioned columns from both tables?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: please add entity classes

Comment: Added entity classes - Product and ProductImage

Comment: just a guess, what happens if you change the method name in the `ProductDetailsDBResult` projection interface from `getProductImages()` to something else which is not clashing with the `Product.getProductImages()` method like `getProductImagesDBResult`?

Comment: As you did't use join fetch , so JPA can't decide which relation to join.So it fetch all data of table and then call all relations.

Comment: Where to mention join fetch?